# Not able to gather facts of ansible host machine

Tags: ansible

Set up module in ansible gives an error when i tried to set custom facts on host machine using control machine

```
---
  - hosts: test-servers
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:

      - name: deleting Facts directory
        file:
          path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/
          state: absent

      - name: Creates a directiory
        file:
          path: /etc/ansible/facts.d/
          recurse: yes
          state: directory

      - name: Copy custom date facts to host machine
        copy:
          src: /app/ansible_poc/roles/custom_facts/templates/facts.d/getdate.fact
          dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/getdate.fact
          mode: 0755

      - name: Copy custom role facts to host machine
        copy:
          src: /app/ansible_poc/roles/custom_facts/templates/facts.d/getrole.fact
          dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/getrole.fact
          mode: 0755


      - name: Reloading facts
        setup:

      - name: Display message
        debug:
          msg: "{{ ansible_local.getdate.date.date }}"

      - name: Display message
        debug:
          msg: "{{ ansible_local.getrole.role.role }}"
```

I get following error when i tried to collect facts of ansible host machine. I have set up a file getdate.fact and getrole.fact which has code respectively

```
#############getdate.fact###############
echo [date]
echo date= `date`
########################################
```

```
#############getrole.fact###############
echo [role]
echo role= `whoami`
########################################
```

and when i tried to run the playbook main.yml then it following error.

```
[root@ansibletower tasks]# ansible -m setup test-servers
192.168.111.28 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/etc/ansible/facts.d/getdate.fact",
    "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error",
    "rc": 8
}
192.168.111.27 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/etc/ansible/facts.d/getdate.fact",
    "msg": "[Errno 8] Exec format error",
    "rc": 8
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you take the time to properly format code in your question. If you're not familiar with markdown, there is editing help available (look for the question mark in the upper left of the question field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" line to your fact scripts.  I.e., getdate.fact should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo [date]
echo date=`date`
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, executables are expected to return JSON:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '{ "date" : "'$( date )'" }'
```